# Calling angular template in quick succession twice

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I would like to know if loading a template URL in quick succession twice can cause a template load error because the second load is expecting the template in the template cache ( since there's already a first load that's not complete ).

I am seeing a tpload error and I am trying to figure out if the above theory that I have is possible.

```
route provider
    when ("/" )
        templateURL : "a.html"
        controller: AController
        resolve : {
            load "/phones"
        }   
    when ("/phones")
        templateURL : "b.html"
        controller: BController
        resolve : {
            load "/"
        }
```

I am seeing an infinite digest error ( because of the cycle I guess ) but I am also seeing a tpload error thrown by $compile .

Note : The illustration is only for the purpose of providing an example. This is not code that I expect to run. More of a rough idea to convey what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: what is this `load`? Not to mentioned, that it should be `templateUrl` - not `templateURL`

Comment: Nothing in code shown shares templates. Provide relevant code

Answer (score -1):

The load errors you are seeing are most likely caused by :

```
templateURL:
```

should be:

```
templateUrl:
```

and your resolve doesn't make any sense at all. Showing the actual code will give you much better answers.